# Fetch current month date from database

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to fetch current month Anniversary date from database but i can't do it.
my query is given below but its not working.

```
qry = "Select Anniversary_Date From Family_Information WHERE DATEADD(Year,DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(Year, Anniversary_Date),Anniversary_Date) >= GETDATE()";
```

Comment: query issue resolved..?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause

```
SELECT...FROM...WHERE MONTH(now())=MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(now())=YEAR(GETDate())
```

whould work - anniversaries for current month. I am not sure as to `GETDATE()` what is it?

Comment: i am getting all the date of current month ..i want only todays date related birthdate form any year.

Comment: Oh,ok for only a day, change `YEAR` to `DAY` and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT Anniversary_Date
FROM Family_Information
WHERE ((DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(Year, Anniversary_Date)
AND (DATEPART(Month, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(Month, Anniversary_Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
 qry = "SELECT Anniversary_Date
FROM Family_Information
WHERE ((DATEPART(Year, GETDATE())) = DATEPART(Year, Anniversary_Date)
AND    (DATEPART(Month, GETDATE())) = DATEPART(Month, Anniversary_Date))" ;
```

Comment: this query showing below error..Incorrect syntax near ')'.Somehow i cant solve it